# Arrangements in probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A company produce in great quantity of mothers cards. The probability that a mother card presents a defect is 0.01. Six mothers cards are successively taken from this production.
I need to calculate the probability that exactly two mother cards from the sampled mother cards are defective.
My answer is 0.01* Arrangements (2,6)

Comment: In probability the word '' succsevily '' mean arrangements?

Comment: So it's 0.01/arrangement (2,6)?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Comment: @ N.F.Taussig. Not exactly

Comment: I have never seen "*Arrangements(2,6)*" used before as notation.  Where are you from out of curiosity?  What does *Arrangements(2,6)* represent and what does it equal?  $15$? $30$?  Something else?  I've seen nearly a dozen different notations for binomial coefficients, but not this one.

Comment: @JMoravitz it's 6!/4!=30

Comment: The punchline is that you will need each card that should be defective *actually be defective* and each card that shouldn't be defective *actually not be defective*.  You have several multiplications of $0.01$ and several multiplications of $0.99$ going on, one for each card.  Not just a single multiplication by $0.01$ like you have here.  As for notation for binomial coefficients, use whatever notation your teacher uses for now... that is fine, but know that most of the rest of the world uses $\binom{n}{k}$ or sometimes $C(n,k)$ if they don't have the ability to use the other.

Comment: @Simooujd in that case then no, you should not be using "Arrangements(2,6)" but rather whatever the other one is you have access to... the one that equals $15$.

Comment: But in out courses we use arrangements "A" for '' with successively '' and the combinaisons "C"  for " without successively"

Comment: You need to recognize that "*successively*" or "*order matters*" might apply only to specific aspects of the problem.  Here, when considering what possibilities exist we are counting the number of different cases we could have in terms of patterns of defective (d) and normal (n) cards we could get.  The patterns look like ddnnnn, dndnnn, dnndnn, dnnndn, dnnnnd, nddnnn, ... and so on.  You should know that if we wanted to count how many such patterns there are we use binomial coefficients... "combinations."  This is because we are not making a distinction between the d's in ddnnnn.

Comment: Using your "Arrangements(2,6)" that would be counting the list 12nnnn, 21nnnn, 1n2nnn, 2n1nnn, 1nn2nn, 2nn1nn, and so on...  That is twice as much as we wanted to count.

Comment: Okey I understand now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is a textbook example of a problem about the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

There are $\binom{6}{2}$ different orders that we could have pulled cards in where exactly two of them are defective.  For example the order `ddnnnn`.

For each of those possible orders, the probability of having actually pulled defective cards and normal cards in that particular order will be $0.01\times 0.01\times 0.99\times 0.99\times 0.99\times 0.99$.  (*Recognize that for another order, we could have just swapped these multiplications around but regardless how we swap them around we will always have two instances of $0.01$ and four instances of $0.99$ being multiplied together*).  It follows then that by adding up all of the distinct possible cases we could be in together we get a final total of:

$$\binom{6}{2}\times 0.01^2\times 0.99^4$$

(*N.B. here I use $\binom{n}{k}$ to represent the binomial coefficient $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.  In your notation I suppose this might be Combinations(2,6) instead?  Know that your notation is uncommon.  It is far more common for the larger number to appear first, such as C(6,2), and also more common to use a shorter notation that uses less space.  Again, in the end you should use whatever notation your teacher uses while in their class, but you should familiarize yourself with other notations in case you wish to communicate about these things elsewhere.*)